# check in a given math function how many zeros exist in a given interval

Tags: math, computational-geometry, symbolic-math, computation

Recently I've been asking myself this question. I know a way to solve it consisting in having a certain x step, and then testing the value of f(x). If f(x).f(x before) < 0, then i know that alteast one zero is there. However, i don't know how to configure the step to include all zeros. This because functions can change how much zeros they have in a given interval greatly. For example, sin(100*x)(blue graph) compared to sin(x)(red graph).

I appreciate you could help me on this one.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a general solution that would work for all mathematical functions. In the case of polynomials, you can use [Sturm's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm's_theorem). In the case of `sin(x*k)` it is `x * pi / k`.

You will have to detect the specific type of function you are working with and then count the roots depending on that.